# 12 volt 8000 watt battery discharge protection

Tags: batteries, discharge, shunt

We built a home in a country where electricity is a rare ressource. In order to have energy available all day we bought a bunch of solar panels and several 12 volt batteries. We then used a 8000 watt inverter to power the house.

We are concerned about battery life so we thought about adding an automatic shut off to disconnect the load when the battery discharge to a critical level.

At first we wanted to add a contactor or a relay with a voltage meter to trigger the relay and disconnect the load. The problem is finding a relay that can handle a 8000 watt load on a 12 volt circuit is quite hard.

The other solutions is to use the inverter built in switch to cut off the load. The inverter came with a module that you plug in to remotly power off and power on the inverter. It would be pretty easy to hook it up to a small relay.

I have been looking online for a solution but most module I found only handles a maximum of 100 amp load, since the inverter is capable of 8000 watt I don't think 100 amp would be enough, maybe I'm wrong?

We do not want to spend over 300$ and the module cannot be too heavy since we are limited with transport.

I'm reaching out to the community for a solution.

Edit: I think the safest and easiest solution is to use a volt meter that triggers the inverter low voltage switch, using a relay of some sort, when the batteries voltage is too low.
Since the load exceeds 100 amp the load should not go through the volt meter. Maybe by using a shunt, if necessary.

Does anyone know a module that can do that?

Comment: Examine an automotive starter-relay, perhaps from a truck.

Comment: Good Inverters might be around 10W/$ so 8kW may be expensive. Given a deep discharge battery of 12V >1kWh you need 8 for 1 hr storage drawing 8kW.  So the energy storage and conversion costs may be  greater than the panels.

Comment: does the inverter remote control power down the inverter completely? .... or does the inverter still draw small amount of power from the batteries when it is shut down or in standby?

Comment: I suspect the subject must be legally (locally) regulated. You should have already spent amounts to obtain panels and related hardware, and the logical way to proceed would be to check with their manufacturers if they have solutions you need, and if these solutions are certified. If you have already done so, please share.

Comment: Doesn't the inverter have a built-in low battery shut down?

Comment: Just because the solar panel is generating 8kW doesn't mean you're drawing 8kW on the other side of the inverter. In fact, if you were you'd be defying the laws of physics.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf We did but our amp usage is too high.

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist You are right but we need to store the energy when we aren't using it and then use that stored energy during night too keep foods cold and such.

Comment: @jsotola the inverter will still consume a little bit of power but nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Anonymous Unfortunately the country I'm talking about is Haiti. They have very limited resources and there is an out of the box solution but that would cost 4000$ without shipping to Haiti. We are looking for an inexpensive solution.

Comment: @SimonB Unfortunately no.

Comment: @DerStrom8 You are right. Little energy is lost in the form of heat so that means we are drawing a little more energy from the batteries. But assuming we almost never draw 8000 watt from it, it's safe to assume 8000 watt on the other side.

Comment: @DustyMan No, I doubt your house is pulling 8kW at any given time, unless you've got a lot of big appliances running simultaneously.

Comment: @DerStrom8 Isn't it safer to assume the max peak load even though I'm probably never going to draw 8kw?

Comment: @DustyMan Sure it's safer, but there is a such thing as overkill. For example if you turned on everything in your house and you only drew about 1kW, then planning for 8x a realistic number is a bit ridiculous. You should make a power budget to figure out how much everything in your house draws, and maybe allow for 1.5-2x your expected max.

Comment: @DerStrom8 I see what you mean.

Comment: @DustyMan, since the inverter has a remote shutoff that reduces the battery consumption to a very small amount, then why don't you use a couple of car starter relays in parallel for the main switch and transfer that switch only when the inverter is shut down.  .... that way you avoid contact arcing without having to use a snubber of some sort

Comment: @DustyMan you have a lot  of reading to do before you can put the together  a useable energy  storage system.

Comment: @jsotola That is a good idea. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

8000W / 12V = ~666A, which is not going to be trivial to switch.  Most power devices are designed to be run at higher voltages, with lower current to avoid this exact situation.

That being said, most industrial size relays are called contactors. 
If you can

1. 100% guarantee that the contactor will never be switched while under load, and
2. assuming you are not trying to meet building codes,

you could use a three phase contactor with all phases connected in parallel to switch the DC Positive line.

The better overall approach in my opinion would be to use an inverter with a low voltage cutoff!

Comment: Hi, FYI the link in the answer is malformed (and therefore broken), Can you please fix it to point to the intended destination? Thanks. (I'll delete this comment when I see the link is fixed.)

Comment: This is a pretty good idea. I've been doing some readings about contactors. The inverter does come with a low voltage cut off but it doesn't detect the voltage. Maybe a voltage sensor could trigger the low voltage switch to turn off the inverter output?

Comment: That is strange, do you have a link to the inverter you are using?